# Python: ошибка AttributeError

Tags: python

```
d[i[1]] = d.get(i[1], []).append(i[2])
```

Эта строчка выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    condense_csv('data.csv', id_name='ID')
  File "main.py", line 29, in condense_csv
    d[i[1]] = d.get(i[1], []).append(i[2])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Почему то оно не видит, что я указал, что надо добавить пустой список. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Посмотрели уже 4 человека, ответьте пожалуйста!

Comment: Значит `i[1]` содержит `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего значение по ключу i[1] равняется None, поэтому ошибка

Попробуйте, к примеру:

```py
d[i[1]] = (d[i[1]] or []).append(i[2])
# Или
d[i[1]] = (d.get(i[1], []) or []).append(i[2])
```

upd:
Только сейчас заметил, что Вы используете `csv`, поэтому более правильный ответ скорее зависит от данных и их получения, чтобы избавиться от `None`.